# Qt: Switching off 'CoreWlan support' from build

Tags: macos, qt

Our software does not uses network at all. What command line option should i pass to `./configure` script in order to completely disable `CoreWlan support` from Qt build? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

For Qt 4.8 at least, you can't do that using configure, however, commenting this line:

```
macx:contains(QT_CONFIG, corewlan):SUBDIRS += corewlan
```

in file "src/plugins/bearer/bearer.pro" in the Qt source dir, should disable it from the build. No point in linking to something you don't need or if you get build errors like I do on recently released OS X Mavericks. ;)

Answer (score 0):

For Qt 5.9.2 it's

```
configure \
  -no-feature-corewlan
```